# Can't stop nvidia module from loading

Tags: nvidia, bumblebee, systemd

I'm trying to use my nvidia card for compute-only on Ubuntu 16.04, Dell Precision 5510. However, since updating to 16.04, it doesn't work at all. So I followed [this guide](https://lenovolinux.blogspot.si/2016/05/bumblebee-on-lenovo-t440p-nvidia-gt.html) to try and get it working with Bumblebee. However, after blacklisting all the modules, the driver still loads on boot.

Additionally, I get a black screen on boot. I can still switch to the virtual terminal, though.

Here's the last chunk of `/etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf`:

```
# 367
blacklist nvidia-367
blacklist nvidia-367-updates
blacklist nvidia-experimental-367
# Blacklist these, because they'll pull in the nvidia driver
blacklist nvidia_uvm
blacklist nvidia_drm
# Workaround to make sure nvidia-uvm is removed as well
# remove nvidia rmmod nvidia-uvm nvidia
remove nvidia rmmod nvidia-uvm nvidia-drm nvidia_modeset nvidia
```

I ran `update-initramfs -u` after editing this file, though I'm not sure that this is necessary.

The system journal shows that `nvidia-persistenced` is starting at boot, but failing to create the device nodes. It looks like this service is what's causing the nvidia modules to load. However, I can't disable it because it's static.

I finally uninstalled everything nvidia from my laptop, just so I could have a working machine again. So how do I get the nvidia module to not load at boot?